# regex match multiple paterns after sentence

Tags: regex

I want to get all the **names** in the important section ingoring all the the non important names.

**my text:**

```
*** not important
name 1
    details
name 2
    details
*** important
name 3
    details
name 4
    details
```

**what i want:**

```
name 3
name 4
```

**what i have until now:**

this matches all the names

```
(^[^ ].*$)
```

but when i try to get only the important ones it fails

```
\*\*\* important[\s\S]*(^[^ ].*$)
```

or this

```
\*\*\* important[\s\S]*?(^[^ ].*$)
```

example here:
https://regex101.com/r/SdG28O/2

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/SdG28O/4)

```
(?:^\*{3} important$|\G(?!\A))[\s\S]*?\K^[^ ].*
```

Alternatively:

```
(?:^\*{3} important$|\G(?!\A))[\s\S]*?\K^\S.*
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
*** not important
name 1
    details
name 2
    details
*** important
name 3
    details
name 4
    details
```

#### Output

```
name 3
name 4
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:^\*{3} important$|\G(?!\A))` Match either of the following

  - `^\*{3} important$` Match the following

    - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
    - `\*{3}` Match `*` exactly 3 times
    - Match a literal space character
    - `important` Match this literally
    - `$` Assert position at the end of the line
  - `\G(?!\A)` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `[\s\S]*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[^ ]` Match any non-space character: [You can replace this with `\S` instead (for any non-whitespace character) if you prefer](https://regex101.com/r/SdG28O/5)
- `.*` Match any character any number of times

Comment: ✨✨ **MAGIC**  ✨✨

Comment: well i spent some time understanding you solution and now i learned it. thanks a lot!